# How does ReactJS allow me to use const functions before I define them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am curious how you can use a value before you defined it in ReactJS? Here's an example:

```
function CounterApp() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const increaseValueTwice = () => {
    increaseValue() //NOT DEFINED AT THIS POINT
    increaseValue() //NOT DEFINED AT THIS POINT
  }

  const increaseValue = () => {
    setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {counter}
      <br / >
      <button onClick={increaseValue}>Increase value</button>
      <br / >
      <button onClick={increaseValueTwice}>Increase value twice</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**increaseValue()** is used before it's defined and yet there is no issue. I watched some tutorial from 2019 and the guy in the tutorial got an error when trying to do this, yet it works for me even though it shouldn't?

Comment: `increaseValue` is accessed when `increaseValueTwice` is executed which is after it was defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the concept you are looking for is

[Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Basically javascript interpreters first read all variable declarations for a given scope, then start calling the functions. In your case it's more complicated because functions call each other, but it still applies.

It's a logic specific to javascript though, so if you come from other languages it's probably a new thing.

You should be able to replicate this exact thing by running a vanilla js code through browser console or nodejs. It is not react specific.

Answer (score 0):

We can reference const variables in the code even before they are declared, as long as that code is not EXECUTED before the variable declaration.

By the time your function runs (on response to your click event), the const has already been declared.

Comment: Okay, how about if I had this line right after declaring the counter state?

     `useEffect( () => {increaseValueTwice()} , [])`

That also doesn't give an error even though it  runs when component mounts.

Comment: @Stevan What happens depends on when the function that you pass to `useEffect` is executed, in the current version of React, it is executed after the component is mounted (after the component function returns). That means that you will not get any errors.

Comment: @Stevan Yeah, what he said. If you want to get an error, try taking the increaseValue() calls outside of your increaseTwice() function. 

They will try to get executed before they are defined and it will explode.

Comment: @RubenSerrate I tried this and it works. Thanks a lot. It seems it compiles because of the concept of Hoisting I didn't know about (@NicolaRomani explained it very well) but then it blows up as you said it would when ran. Example if anyone runs into this:

`if(counter === 2){  
    console.log(increaseValue())
  }

  const increaseValue = () => {
    setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1);
    return "it ran twice this time"
  };`